# WPF Control Style Setter Property according to item in series

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, infragistics

I'm currently working on a .NET 4.7 application using WPF and infragistics controls.

I need to set the `With`, `Height`, `YMemberPath` and `XMemberPath` of each element according to each element in the data source list.

I use a chart `XamDataChart`, which shows several points from a `List<ChartData>`. The `ChartData` class looks like this:

```
public class ChartData
{
    public double Width { get; set; }

    public double Height { get; set; }

    public double XPos { get; set; }
    public double YPos { get; set; }
}
```

The values are set in the constructor of my ViewModel for now:

```
ChartData data = new ChartData
{
    Width = 400,
    Height = 200,
    XPos = 100,
    YPos = 100
};
```

My XAML looks like this:

```
<ig:XamDataChart.Series>
    <ig:ScatterSeries
        MarkerType="Square"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ChartDataList}"
        YMemberPath="YPos"
        XMemberPath="XPos"
        XAxis="{Binding ElementName=XAxis}"
        YAxis="{Binding ElementName=YAxis}">
        <ig:ScatterSeries.MarkerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ig:Marker}">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, FallbackValue=20}"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, FallbackValue=20}"/>
            </Style>
        </ig:ScatterSeries.MarkerStyle>
    </ig:ScatterSeries>
</ig:XamDataChart.Series>
```

Unfortunately my elements won't get drawn correctly and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

*The Width and Height Setters in the marker style section are not respected at all.*

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this issue?

I need to draw each element without margin or padding at XPos and YPos with proper Height and Width.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to implement property change notification.  When the source values for the width and height are determined and set or change, you need to notify the target of this change.  This will let you know how to do this: [Change Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification).

Basically, you need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) and call OnPropertyChanged() at each property when the value changes

**Edit 1:**
I do not follow.  You are using a binding for Height and Width.  This implies that you want these values to be updated during normal operation.  If this is not correct, just use hard coded values.

Also, your values are not being respected because they are set in the constructor which is run after initialization of the UI.  Without change notification, the values in the constructor will not be respected (which is why they are not properly set on startup).

You could initialize your values in their definition e.g.:

```
public double Width { get; set; } = 400;
```

This value is applied during initialization and should be applied to the initial UI layout during startup - however, without change notification, this becomes a static (un-changing) value.

However, you need to correct your binding.  Your binding is to a RelativeSource but is bound to itself.  This means that you are binding the Control's Width to itself.  You need to bind to the data source, using ElementName= and a Path to the actual data item e.g., Path=data.Width  This is approximate as there is not enough of your code to understand the whole picture. However, again, without change notification, changes to data.Width will not update.

**Edit 2**: 
You may also update the values in the "traditional" manner.  That is, use the name of the control and the property name and set the value in code.  Doing this, the Binding would be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jeff. INotifyPropertyChanged is certainly a good idea - but not quite what I'm looking for just now, unfortunately. The values are not properly set already on application start, if I use static values. I don't know how to set Width and Height in particular, because it's within the MarkerStyle.

Comment: I think you need to set the path="Width" & path = "Height" in your setters.